# Saving Huge record returnd from DB in Memcache with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, facebook, memcached

I am developing a site (using PHP + Memcache) in which users can have friends and is stuck at a point in thinking of saving a list of Friends of a user which has more than 100K friends. Suppose, if user has 100K friends, how would you save them in Memcache? Currently I have this code.

```
$ttl = count($result); //about 10K friends
for($i=0; $i<$ttl; $i++)
{
    $friendslist[$result[$i][0]] = $result[$i]; //$result[$i][0] = Friend's ID
}

$mem->set($usrid,$friendslist);
```

This creates many problems.

1) First of all memory issue and performance in saving and retrieving such huge array.

2) Cannot save more than 1mb in array

Any Einstein have good trick to save such records in memcache? What would be the code to save and retrieve such list? Any idea how Twitter or Facebook would be saving if such huge records are returnd from DB?

Comment: Why aren't you simply adding or removing friends one at a time.  Is it really a requirement that a user be able to paste one hundred thousand brand-new ID's as friends into a single request?

Comment: Why do you need to store so many friends in memecahce? It doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Comment: As others have said, this seems to be an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Why do you need to store all of the user's friends?

Comment: You'll never need to load all 100K friends at once. You would need to do something along the lines of what Facebook does, which is to lazy load them (e.g. using JavaScript) on demand.

Comment: The problem is that when user checks his list of friends then I would have to go and get list from DB if I do not save it in Memcache and that is the problem.

Comment: LIMIT the clause, lazy load the data on scroll via AJAX. No one will want to view thousands of results at once.

Comment: Then would I need to ask Database each AJAX request?

Comment: Yepp. And that is even faster than retrieving large amounts of data to and from memcache. It's not optimized for that! Proof!

Comment: As @AxelAmthor already confirmed, query again if you need to. Don't give the user more data than he/she wants, especially if it's going to chow your memory away.

Comment: @JohnSmith the approach you want to take does not make sense, it is absolutely pointless to cache this data (and so much of it).

Comment: @John Smith: Yes, made some Tests with memcache on a dedicated server and mysql on another, caching data from DB to mc and back. We dropped that, no performance gain at all, at larger amounts it was even slower.

Comment: So you experts say and I think I have to go with calling from DB each request

Comment: Can someone look at what @Abdul Jabbar WebBestow is suggesting so I can have a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you to not save such huge record in single array instead call needed list of friends from Database just like pagination. But if still you need it then I am not sure if this is correct approach or not but you can give it a try.

```
$ttlsets = count($result)/1000; //100K = 100 sets

for($i=0; $i<$ttlsets; $i++)
{
    $friendslist = array();
    for($j=0; $j<100; $j++)
    {
       $friendslist[$result[$i][0]] = $result[$i]; //$result[$i][0] = Friend's ID
    }
    $mem->set($usrid.'set'.$i, $friendslist);
}

$mem->set($usrid.'counter', $ttlsets);
```

Now you have a list of friends with Sets. And you can also check how many sets you have. Now you can AJAX and call each Set individually having 100 friends in one set. So, now you dont have to go DB. But again this is not a full proof solution but shows everything fine till here.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I gave it a try and worked like charm. Though I had to make some other code for AJAX but great with Memcache Sets